# CSS styling of Input multiple

Tags: html, css, input

I'm using the following input field

```
<input class="upload_button" type="file" multiple="" name="userfile">
```

To upload multiple files to a system, I can't work out how to style this with CSS properly, as the button and input box seem to be binded together?!

Comment: do you want to make input field beautiful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use CSS to style `<input type="file"/>` element directly; this is a precaution used by web browsers to prevent user's into being tricked into uploading files.

But there are techniques that work around it, using transparency that works well.
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: Wow, lot of answers very quickly - thanks everybody for your help - I'll look into the quirksmode link, seems like it would do the job nicely. Thanks Scott.

Comment: No problem. Good luck, let us know if you get stuck with anything.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have much experience with it but i found a link which might help you:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Answer (score 0):

You should make type="file" multiple with `z-index:-1;` for example and make image appear 
(with `z-index:1;`) in the same place where is your input file field.

Answer (score 0):

As Scott said, you can't directly style some input elements because they are dependent on your environment (browser and OS). I have not had great luck using workarounds, and prefer solutions that replace them elegantly. One i like in particular is uniform.js.

http://uniformjs.com/